# Anchor link to app with parameters, google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, anchor

I have the following anchors in my html template:

```
<a href="<?!= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?>"><button>All Feedback</button></a>
<a href="<?!= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"&filter=bomgar" ?>"><button>Bomgar Feedback</button></a>
<a href="<?!= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"&filter=tickets" ?>"><button>Ticket Feedback</button></a>
```

When navigating to the links with parameters, the "&" and "=" symbols are %26 and %3d in the url. Is there a way to prevent this from happening ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add GET parameters to a URL, you should use the `?` character to introduce them (instead of the `&` character). The ampersand is used to add multiple variables. So your URL should look like this.

```
http://script.google.com/[.......]/exec?variable=data&otherVariable=otherData
```

So since you didn't have the `?`, the URL was sanitized to eliminate those characters.

This [web app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyNYYnoX-Akyw_ccq1q2LAGLFPqn2HdSixe0TN8wGO3mtMSOhHD/exec) that I made illustrates the difference.

```
<a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?filter=bomgar" ?>"><button>Bomgar Feedback</button></a>
```