# Structure of Google Docs Based Volunteer Management System

Tags: google-apps-script

Here's what I would like to be able to do. The point of this is to manage the various volunteers necessary to make our church run every Sunday.

Have a Google Docs spreadsheet with the names of the volunteers and which roles they are willing to staff (for example, Tim volunteers to be an usher; Ana volunteers to be a lector).

Have a separate sheet listing every volunteer position that needs to be filled for the next 6 months (for example, we need 2 ushers and 1 lector on Sunday).

Write a Google Apps Script that will go through the list of positions that need to be filled and choose the next volunteer to be asked to fill that position (probably based on who has filled this role the FEWEST number of times in the past). The script would then send an e-mail to that volunteer and ask if they are available for that position. Ideally, the e-mail would be HTML based and would include 2 links in it: 1 for them to click to accept that position and 1 for them to click to decline that position.

If the volunteer accepts that position, the script adds their name to that position. If the volunteer declines that position, the script moves on to the NEXT volunteer and sends the same e-mail.

The script continues this process until either all of the slots are filled or all the volunteers have declined.

I can conceptualize of everything that I would need to do on this EXCEPT the links in the e-mail.

Does anybody have any suggestions for ways to dynamically generate links like this?

Any other thoughts for how I can structure my script to do what I want?

Obviously, I'm still in the thinking-it-through phase, so I'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks in advance. (And the members of our little church thank you, too!)

Answer (score 1):

Generating links is of course possible! [I wrote up an answer recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914955/how-to-call-google-apps-script-from-web-page/14915184#14915184). You don't need all parts of that answer. Maybe you should [look at this answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733831/anchor-link-to-app-with-parameters-google-apps-script/14738143#14738143).

Anyways, a bit of sample/psuedo-code.

```
var scriptUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(); //URL to invoke your script

var message = "blah blah event details blah blah"
    +" <a href=\""+scriptUrl+"?user="+user+"&accept=no\">Decline</a>"
    +" or <a href=\""+scriptUrl+"?user="+user+"&accept=yes\">Accept</a>";

MailApp.sendEmail(recipent,subject,"",{htmlBody:message});
```

Then you handle it by using the doGet(e) parameters that I explained in the answers above.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var user = e.parameter.user;
  var accept = e.parameter.accept;

  if (accept=="yes") {
    //he/she accepted!!
  } else {
    //he/she declined. =(
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Phil. Thanks for your response. You have me very excited because I think this might work. But I'm also a little confused. I'm with you on creating the e-mail with the 2 dynamic URLs. And I understand the idea behind doGet(e) parameters. But I don't know where I'm developing the doGet(e) code. Following the links generated by your "pseudo-code" above takes me to a URL: "http://null/?user=test&accept=no". I'm missing a big piece of your solution, but I don't get what. Thanks again!

Comment: Well ... I might be more with you than I though. I wrote the doGet(e) code into its own function, then deployed that function as a web app, which gave me a URL. Then, I replaced the scriptUrl variable in the original function with the URL from the newly depoloyed web app. Which--combining the ?user and &accept code--gives me the ability to pass (e) parameters to the web app. Right? But when I try to execute from the links in my e-mails, it says "TypeError: Cannot read property "accept" from undefined."

Comment: Just as a note, you should add `&eventId=SOMETHING` that way you have some idea of what event they were accepting or declining. ALSO, I realized I had a typo in the word `parameter`. Please fix your code appropriately.

Comment: Standby ... spelling error. (ID10T error, right?!). Maybe I can sort myself out.

Comment: Yeah, I gotcha on the event thing, Phil. Thanks.

Comment: This is going to be AWESOME!

Comment: Nope. Still getting "TypeError: Cannot read property "accept" from undefined."

Comment: There might be a typo in your code. I posted a working example here. http://pastebin.com/1n4s8N9t